# python stdout to who signaled me

Tags: python, linux, python-2.6, centos6

I am using a custom signal to get the state of a service.

It simply prints out the number of active threads.

My problem is it always does it to the shell that executed it not to the one that sent the signal obviously.

Since this will run as a service this can cause it to crash once the session that starts it is closed.

I have been googling for a way to output the message to the session that sent the signal but I can't seem to find one.

I have seen other services do things like this so it must be possible.. but how?

```
def status_catch(signal, frame):
  print 'Active threads:', (threading.activeCount() - 1)
signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, status_catch)
```

Comment: Which other services do this ?

Comment: Please expand on the httpd idea. What do you see printed and how do you trigger it ?

Comment: Look here: http://www.liquidweb.com/kb/use-httpd-fullstatus-to-monitor-apache-status/

Comment: Are you sure the `httpd` that you start isn't just somehow connecting to the server and printing normally to stdout ? Don't have httpd here, do a `strace httpd status` and see what it does.

Comment: I am calling it like this # service https fullstatus

Comment: Thank you. I figured it out.

Comment: What did you end up doing ?

Comment: Made the signal write a file and had the bash cat the contents and then remove it.